# Powershell ignoring look behind regular expression to return entire line

Tags: regex, powershell

A simple enough question I hope.

I have a text log file that includes the following line:

> 123,010502500114082000000009260000000122001T

I want to search through the log file and return the "00000000926" section of the above text. So I wrote a regular expression:
(?<=123.{17}).{11}

So when the look behind text equals '123' with 17 characters, return the next 11. This works fine when tested on online regex editors. However in Powershell the entire line is returned instead of the 11 characters I want and I can't understand why.

```
$InputFile = get-content logfile.log
$regex = '(?<=123.{17}).{11}'
$Inputfile | select-string $regex
```

(entire line is returned).

Why is powershell returning the entire line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're using `Select-String` which returns the line that matches (think `grep`).

```powershell
$InputFile = get-content logfile.log | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '(?<=123.{17})(.{11})') {
        $Matches[1]
    }
}
```

Haven't tested this, but it should work (or something similar).

Comment: Makes sense and using -match instead of select-string worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Don't discount `Select-String` just yet. Like [Briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29851949/3829407) says it is doing what you want it to *but* you need to extract the data you *actually* want in one of two ways. `Select-String` returns `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` objects and not just raw strings. Also we are going to use `Select-String`'s ability to take file input directly.

```
$InputFile = "logfile.log"
$regex = '(?<=123.{17}).{11}'
Select-string $InputFile -Pattern $regex | Select-Object -ExpandProperty  Matches | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

Of if you have at least PowerShell 3.0

```
(Select-string $InputFile -Pattern $regex).Matches.Value
```

Which gives in both cases

```
00000009260
```

Comment: Hehe I figured there was probably a way, but for some reason I never use `Select-String`. +1

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need the lookaround regex for that:

```
$InputFile = get-content logfile.log
$InputFile -match '123.{28}' -replace '123.{17}(.{11}).+','$1'
```